# PyCharm: History of Tests?

Tags: pycharm

Does PyCharm have a history of the tests which I executed during the last hours?

Background:

I start insisde `test_big_foo()` for method `big_foo()` and notice that a helper method needs to updated.

I update `helper_method()` and update its unittest `test_helper_method()`.

This takes some time.

Now I want to pop one item of my workstack.

That's why I would like to see the history of the tests in PyCharm.

My next action would be to rerun `test_big_foo()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `Pin tab` feature of PyCharm: right click on the tab or click to the  [image] button. After that this tab will stay, so you can see what have been executed.

Other way to do that is clicking on `Import Test Results` [image] button, which would give you possibility to switch to recent test executions:

[image]

Comment: The "Import Test Results" does what I want. I never clicked on that icon, since the name was misleading me. Thank you very much. The length of the list of the directly available last tests could be longer. I could not find a a way to increase the length of this list

Comment: I've found a [chunk of code](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/c26ad1220f3ea914c516388f415b1db62a01414f/platform/smRunner/src/com/intellij/execution/testframework/sm/runner/history/actions/AbstractImportTestsAction.java#L69), responsible for the number of tests, but setting `<property name="test_history_size" value="100" />` in the `.idea/workspace.xml` file (`PropertiesComponent` section) didn't helped. Maybe you would have better luck, with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable logging for console output. Configure it from `Run/Debug configurations`. Check the option which says `Save console output to a file`.
[image]

Comment: How can I rerun test_big_foo() with you solution?

Answer (score 0):

Alt+Shift+F10 Shows a popup window "Run".

There you can select the last tests you run.

I think this list is too short, but it's better than nothing.