# Extend Test History in PyCharm

Tags: testing, pycharm, automated-tests, ide, test-runner

PyCharm has a great feature of allowing us to look into the test history:

[image]

However, that history only shows a couple of test runs. In my scenario, I ran all tests from the project and then started to debug individual red tests. I wanted somehow to keep track of the red tests, but while debugging, this history gets populated with more stuff, so I eventually lose this history. I used the trick of running the entire test suite and only debugging the individual tests. That way, I can switch between the tabs and still have the history of all tests. But if I accidentally click "Run", I lose this information and have to re-run everything again.

My question is: Is it possible to configure this history to have more than 10 entries? Is this history stored somewhere else, where I could take a look at?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the only way to configure the number of tests is editing a value in the configuration file [see this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44327777/pycharm-history-of-tests#comment75989909_44453592). The short default value (10) is to prevent the test history from getting polluted with too many results. I'm not aware that this value can be configured in Settings. The alternative is using a run configuration with logging for your tests and manage clean up by launching a costum before launch script there.

Comment: When you run the tests the console should show the path to the temporary project specific directory (it's a default path hidden somewhere in your IDE user files). There you can see the temporary history files being saved and how the oldest start getting automatically deleted when you reach the maximum number of temporary test history files.